# Wordpress default menu in database

Tags: menus, database

There are 3 menus in my wordpress(3.5) now.

- Main menu (default from wp)
- Footer menu (default from wp)
- Test menu

Now I have kept test menu as default.

Where does Wordpress store this thing?

I want to know where wordpress stores about current menu that is displaying in the front end.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Menu by itself is a taxonomy in WP. It means that you can find all menus in `wp_terms` table, by running following query:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM wp_terms AS t
  LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS tt ON tt.term_id = t.term_id
 WHERE tt.taxonomy = 'nav_menu';
```

Menu item is custom post type in WP. They are stored in `wp_posts` table. You can find all of them by using this query:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM wp_posts 
 WHERE post_type = 'nav_menu_item';
```

Relations between menus and menu items are stored in `wp_term_relationships` table. To find all items of specific menu you can use this query:

```
SELECT p.* 
  FROM wp_posts AS p 
  LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships AS tr ON tr.object_id = p.ID
  LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS tt ON tt.term_taxonomy_id = tr.term_taxonomy_id
 WHERE p.post_type = 'nav_menu_item'
   AND tt.term_id = /*your menu ID*/;
```

Information about currently select menu is located in `wp_options` table as serialized PHP array. For example if we use TwentyEleven theme, then we will have a record in `wp_options` table with `option_name` column equals to `theme_mod_twentyeleven` and `option_value` column equals to `...;s:18:"nav_menu_locations";a:1:{s:7:"primary";i:103;}}`. Here you can see that menu with `term_id` equals to 103 is currently selected as `"primary"` menu.

The key principle here is that we always have separate options record for each WP theme. Such options have the same name structure: `theme_mods_{your-theme-name}`.

P.S.: To change current menu in the admin panel, just go to `Appearance` » `Menus` page and select menu you need in `Theme Locations` meta box:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply but
I want to know where it stores the menu which is default (showing to front end) now.

Comment: @HirenRathod I have updated my answer

Comment: Yes, I got the answer. I'm using hypershot theme and kept primery menu as test menu.
It stores like this
a:2:{i:0;b:0;s:18:"nav_menu_locations";a:2:{s:11:"header-menu";i:27;s:11:"footer-menu";i:0;}}
Here i:27 means 27 is the term_id from wp_terms.
Thanks @eugene-manuilov :)

Comment: How would you select the menu items (pages/posts/links) for a given `term_id`?