# Insert menus in the database

Tags: menus, database

I want to create a large menu structure, and the admin pages time out, so I cannot insert them via the admin screens.

How can I insert the menu entries directly in the database?

Thank you

Comment: Why do the admin pages time out?

Comment: @sri: It's a [known bug in WordPress](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/14134).

Comment: Indeed its a subtle bug, appearing for large menu structures only. I do hope its fixed in v4.0 due out August 2014. 

In the meantime, I try to add the menus directly in the database.

Comment: I found the answer, it is here:

http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/78316/wordpress-default-menu-in-database

Thank you